# Multiple SCNActions

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am quite new to the SceneKit development.
I am writing my game which has some complex SCNActions logic.
By complex I mean that there are SCNActions, which run other actions in their completion handler block, so it is be something like this:

```
SCNAction.runAction(..., completionHandler -> {
  SCNAction.runAction(..., completionHandler -> {
     SCNAction.runAction (..., completionHandler -> {
       SCNAction.runAction (..., completionHandler -> {
})
})
})
 })
```

Then I have to stop a user interactions in some cases if some actions are completed and I am not able to do this, still my logic is not correct and there are errors in the game.

Could you tell me please is it a valid approach or should I avoid using SCNActions at all?

Comment: SCNActions are a great functionality in SceneKit, but everything depends on the entire logic you create. It is possible to trigger new SCNActions by the termination of an other SCNAction. You can also chain SCNActions using the sequence property, or let them run forever. As you provide not much of the logic you are using, I cannot tell you what's going on in your case. Could you post more of the real code you are using, by editing your question?

Comment: @ZAY: I think that there is no need, it would be to much code, to be honest I think that it is not the best quality as I was experimenting a lot. I think that I need to do a complete / partial rewrite.

Comment: no problem, feel free to update your question as necessary